# Why does Cura remove a part of a model when slicing?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing

Some parts of [this model](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:6304780) when slicing in Cura are just being deleted.

Here is the part of the model before slicing; notice how there is a wall between the threads and the inside
[image]

And after slicing, that wall is just gone, and this wouldn't be practical to print.
[image]

And turning on supports doesn't fix the problem in the slightest.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What the nozzle size 0.4mm? And what's the model height approximately, did you scale it?

Comment: Nozzle is 0.4mm, scale is X: ~75, Y: ~75, Z: 45.5, I have not scaled the model at all.

Comment: What version of Cura do you use? Latest 5.5? My guess is that there is simply to little space in the model to be sliced in that resolution. I would probably change the design a bit, or scale the whole model up, or maybe it's fixable with using a higher Wall Line Count and Wall Thickness. I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm on 5.3.1, I'll try updating to 5.6 and changing the settings you suggested

Comment: Scaling it up seems to fix the issue, but I have to scale it up to almost 150% for it to work again, but I don't want to print this at this size, so changing the model seems to be the only option.

Comment: Print with a 0.2mm nozzle at higher resolution?

Comment: Sadly I don't have a smaller nozzle, I ended up using PrusaSlicer instead which got it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments. Probably the model contains too little space for the slicer to be able to slice for that nozzle size and resolution.

You have a few options:

- Scale up the model
- Use a smaller nozzle and a higher resolution
- Change the model to include thicker walls

Maybe you can increase wall thickness in slicer settings and achieve the same, although I am not sure of it.

As mentioned by you, apparently PrusaSlicer did work. It's interesting to figure out what the actual difference is. Isn't it just the wrong visualization in Cura? Did you try to print that Cura-sliced model or preview it top-down layer for layer?

Comment: All of these solutions would for sure work; but none of them are applicable to this model. I got this model from online and changing it would be a hassle, I don't have a smaller nozzle, and I would have to scale it up a ton for it to work. Cura's preview was very confident about printing it the way it showed, so I don't think it was a rendering bug. PrusaSlicer seems to be more lenient with very thin walls, so it sliced correctly.

Comment: *Note:* If the walls are really less than 0.4 mm thick, then that thread will be very fragile, even if you get it to print correctly.